# dbunit schema issues with h2 and oracle, schema is always PUBLIC

Tags: oracle, database-schema, h2, dbunit, in-memory-database

From a previous export of an Oracle DB, i have both xml and dtd files with lots of data but dbunit seems to ignore the dtdfiles when i try to import the data.

```
flatXMLBuilder.build(xmlFile);
```

I always get this errormessage when trying to reference one object of a table:

```
ERROR Table 'TABLE' not found in tableMap=org.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap
```

and the warning:

```
WARN  session=global o.d.database.DatabaseConnection - The given schema 'SA' does not exist
```

I am not sure if the including of the dtd files would fix the schemaproblem (which is always set to PUBLIC)
But i would be happy if i at least could test it out.
The files are always in the same directory:

T1.xml
T1.dtd

Also the core problem seems to be the schema which is always set to PUBLIC on my target H2 in memory db. 
I tried out some schema set methods like "set schema" or "init=create schema" in the connection url but the currentschema was always public.

So when i was logged in as the SA user for example i couldn't find any tables becaue in the SA schema are no tables only in PUBLIC.

I also tried the setSchema(String) method on the h2connection but it don't work (i get an uncatchable error on call)

Update:
Currently i use a FileInputStream to read the dtd file and add it to the builder:

```
builder.setMetaDataSetFromDtd(dtdStream);
```

But it didn't help with the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a schema `x`, and also set the default schema to `x`, in the database URL, then you need to use:

```
jdbc:h2:~/data/databaseName;init=create schema if not exists x\;set schema x
```

Please note the escaped semicolon. In Java, you need to escape the backslash as well:

```
String url = "jdbc:h2:~/data/databaseName;init=create schema if not exists x\\;set schema x";
```

This URL is a bit long. You might want to move all the statements to an init script, and just run that:

```
jdbc:h2:~/data/databaseName;init=runscript 'init.sql'
```

Comment: Hello, it seems i didn't use a correct syntax at all on the connection url. With your version the schema is set. But the problem of missing tables still exsits, i will continue my research tomorrow

Comment: BTW. Is there a possibility that i can use your h2 webtool to connect and take a peek in the h2 memory db? (my current config is (jdbc:h2:mem:db1;+Schema)

Comment: Yes, but you can't use an in-memory database, so you need to use `jdbc:h2:~/data...` and not `jdbc:h2:mem:...`. And then, append `;auto_server=true` to the database URL. Or use the server mode (but that's a bit more complicated).

Comment: where to place `init.sql` so it's visible to H2? I get error `FileNotFoundException: init.sql (No such file or directory)"; "init.sql"; SQL statement:
runscript from 'init.sql' [90031-197]`